# Trying to use: zbstudio.exe -cfg "ini=false" but where do I put the path and filename of my alternative ini file?

Tags: zerobrane

With the above I get the error msg below in the console:

Can't open file 'ini=false': the system cannot find the file specified.

It's trying to open the filename 'ini=false'!?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`ini=false` is the default value. The documentation you referenced provides several examples: `ini='file.ini'` will create `file.ini` in the default system-dependent location, `ini='./file.ini'` will create `file.ini` in the ZeroBrane Studio folder, and `ini='d:/file.ini'` will create `file.ini` in the root directory of the `D:` drive.

I don't get any error messages in the console when I run it with `zbstudio.exe -cfg "ini=false"`.

Comment: Apologies, this is exactly what Im doing. zbstudio is already running (no cmd line args) - all good. I then try to start a new instance with C:\utility\zb170\zbstudio.exe -cfg "singleinstance=false"; "ini=c:\utility\zbs_2.ini". The 2nd zbstudio instance takes a long while to start then its console says: "Found auto-recovery record and restored saved session.""Can't open file 'ini=c:\utility\zbs_2.ini': the network path was not found." (i confirm the c:\utility\zbs_2.ini exists).

Comment: I also just tried a single zbstudio instance with: C:\utility\zb170\zbstudio.exe -cfg "ini=c:\utility\zbs_2.ini". For this I got the console error: "Error while loading configuration string: '[string "ini=c:\utility\zbs_2.ini"]:1: '<name>' expected near '\''."

Comment: You are providing an additional parameter, which breaks the command line; try `C:\utility\zb170\zbstudio.exe -cfg "singleinstance=false; ini=[[c:\utility\zbs_2.ini]]"`. Also, the path is a normal Lua value, so needs to be properly quoted.

Comment: Works! Thanks very much Paul! (I'm always working in 2+ Lua projects at once, so two+ Zerobrane instances each with their own set of open files and project tree makes it efficient and clear.)

Comment: Yes, this approach should work. You can accept the answer if it gave you the information you were looking for.